# Combine two sets of intervals to one set of intervals

Tags: python, intervals

I have two ordered sets of intervals (`(` means "start" and `)` means "stop"):

```
      1: (          )              (          )
         0---1------3------5---6---7------9---10----> time
      2: (   )(            )   (          )
```

In two list it would look like:

```
intervals1 = [(0,3), (7,10)]
intervals2 = [(0,1), (1,5), (6,9)]
```

The further evaluation of the time series will be an integration over time of both. For that, I would like to keep the interval character but as common intervals. In the given example, the time series and corresponding list would look like:

```
common: (   )(     )(     )   (   )(     )(  )
        0---1------3------5---6---7------9---10----> time
intervals = [(0,1), (1,3), (3,5), (6,7), (7,9), (9,10)]
```

How can I combine these two time series efficiently?

Comment: Have you tried to code this yourself?

Comment: @pstatix: Your answer merges the two lists.

Comment: I would probably use an algorithm like [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/69242/merging-overlapping-intervals) to merge the time intervals, while also recording "starts" and "ends". Then use your list of starts and ends to split the intervals.

Comment: I was able to generate the possible pairs but you don't need `(5,6)` which is generated by my code: `lst = list(set(sorted(np.array(intervals1+intervals2).flatten())));`
`output = [(lst[i], lst[i+1]) for i in range(len(lst)-1)];` `print (output)`. Perhaps one can play with these lines to reach the desired solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can efficiently solve this issue with a stack based algorithm, since you know that no more than two intervals can overlap at any given position:

```
def merge_intervals(a, b):
    stack = sorted(a+b, reverse=True)

    while len(stack) > 1:
        first = stack.pop()
        second = stack.pop()
        if first == second:         # identical intervals can be merged
            yield first
        elif first[1] <= second[0]: # no overlapping, yield first interval, put back second
            yield first
            stack.append(second)
        elif first[0] == second[0]: # overlap at start, yield shorter, put back rest of longer
            if first[1] > second[1]:
                first, second = second, first
            yield first
            stack.append((first[1], second[1]))
        elif first[1] < second[1]:  # partial overlap, yield first two parts, put back rest
            yield first[0], second[0]
            yield second[0], first[1]
            stack.append((first[1], second[1]))
        else: # first[1] >= second[1] # total envelopment
            yield first[0], second[0]
            yield second
            if first[1] != second[1]:
                stack.append((second[1], first[1]))

    yield from stack # there may or may not be one element left over
```

This is a generator, so you'll get your desired output with:

```
intervals = list(merge_intervals(intervals1, intervals2))
```

Comment: Great, that answers the question nicely. Unfortunately, I am not able to extend it to intervals with values which have to be remembered between the new intervals.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "values which have to be remembered between the new intervals". Would zero-width intervals work to represent them? The only issue with that would be making sure you don't accidentally merge them with overlapping intervals from the other list that happen to begin or end on the same number, but with a few tests, my code may just work.